# Check if element from list is inside another list in django template

Tags: python, django

I'm making a `for loop` through a list. For each element in this list, I would like to know if this element could be egal to one of 4 words from another list.

This is my example in order to describe the situation:

From my view:

```
content = ['**Added**:\n', '* something (toto-544)\n', '\n', '**Changed**:\n', ...]

operations = ['Added', 'Changed', 'Fixed', 'INTERNAL']
```

From my HTML file:

```
{% for line in content %}
  {% if line in operations %}
    <tr class="table-subtitle">
      <td colspan="12">{{ line }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% else %}
    <tr class="table-value-content">
      <td colspan="12">{{ line }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

It should display the first `line` element different than the second one (I changed color between both classes). Because `line[0]` is in `operations` and not `line[1]`.

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work through my `for loop`/`if statement` ?

Comment: `'Added'` and `'**Added**:\n'` are not same

Comment: @Your right ! I believe `in` worked like `icontains` ! Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This check is a bit complex for a template, but you can easily achieve it in Python code using the [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function.
Since the strings are longer, you could check if the operations are `in` the string:

```
any(
    op.lower() in s.lower()
    for op in operations)
```

Test code:

```
content = ['**Added**:\n', '* something (toto-544)\n', '\n', '**Changed**:\n',]
operations = ['Added', 'Changed', 'Fixed', 'INTERNAL']

for s in content:
    print()
    print('s:', repr(s))
    print('s in operations:', s in operations)
    print('custom check:   ', any(op.lower() in s.lower() for op in operations))
```

The result is:

```
s: '**Added**:\n'
s in operations: False
custom check:    True

s: '* something (toto-544)\n'
s in operations: False
custom check:    False

s: '\n'
s in operations: False
custom check:    False

s: '**Changed**:\n'
s in operations: False
custom check:    True
```

Comment: Excellent explanation ! Thank you very much for this information @Ralf

Answer (score 2):

As said @shourav `'Added'` and `'**Added**:\n'` is not the same thing. It was a mistake from me because I believed `in` worked like `icontains`.